# get list of addresses (ansible_host) from a group of servers

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible inventory with this format:

```
[servers:children]
s1
s2
s3

[s1]
10.10.0.80 hostname=s1.example.com

[s2]
10.10.1.80 hostname=s2.example.com

[s3]
jail_s3 ansible_host=10.10.2.80 ansible_port=2222 hostname=s3.example.com
```

I would like to get a comma-separated of all the ansible hosts belonging to the group `servers`, for this, I have been using:

```
ips = "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'sites') | map('ipaddr') | join(',') }}"
```

But the problem I have now with this inventory is that `query('inventory_hostnames')` don't return the IP for `s3` instead returns a string `jail_3` the output of the list is like:

```
'10.10.0.80'
'10.10.1.80'
'jail_s3'
```

I found that I could use a `loop` and filter the output something like this:

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ item if (item| ipaddr) else  hostvars[item].ansible_host }}"
loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames','servers') }}"
```

Or in a template within a loop:

```
{% for host in query('inventory_hostnames', 'servers') %}
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_host|default(hostvars[host].inventory_hostname) }}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, the filter `ipaddr` returns false for `jail_s3` and then I fall back to `hostvars[item].ansible_host`.

This works but I would like to know if it could be done in "one-liner" probably by using a `map`, or something that could take the list of `query('inventory_hostnames','servers') | ???`

Any ideas?